# push array instead o string in react native

Tags: react-native, push

I want to push my data in array but it shows me string in react native. 
My code is like that:

```
const dataSource = responseJson.old_cases.reduce(function (sections, item) {
    let section = sections.find(section => section.gender === item.gender);
    
    if (!section) {
        section = { gender: item.gender,data:[] };
        sections.push(section);
    }
    
    section.data.push(item.name)
    return sections;
}, []);

this.setState({dataSource: dataSource // Pass the dataSource that we've processed above});
```

Output of my code is

```
[
    {"gender": "Male", "data": ["name_1", "name_2"]}, 
    {"gender": "Female", "data": ["name_3", "name_4",'name_5']},
]
```

as you see names are string I need that kind of output

```
[
    {"gender": "Male", "data": [{"name_1"}, {"name_2"}]}, 
    {"gender": "Female", "data": [{"name_3"}, {"name_4"},{'name_5'}]},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot apply string values inside the objects.

like.

```
[
    {"gender": "Male", "data": [{"name_1"}, {"name_2"}]}, 
    {"gender": "Female", "data": [{"name_3"}, {"name_4"},{'name_5'}]},
]
```

We have to apply key-value pairs like below:

```
section.data.push({ [item.name]: item.name })
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy this and replace for your code, I think it's what you need. But I'm not sure.

```
const dataSource = responseJson.old_cases.reduce(function (sections, item) {
        let section = sections.find(section => section.gender === item.gender);
        
        if (!section) {
            section = { gender: item.gender,data:[] };
            sections.push(section);
        }
        
        section.data.push({[item.name]: item.name})
        return sections;
    }, []);
    
    this.setState({dataSource: dataSource // Pass the dataSource that we've processed above});
```